# how to jump to table in rubymine 6/intellji rails model dependency diagram

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ruby, ide, intellij-idea, rubymine

I remember there was a keyboard shortcut we used back in the day.. any ideas? or at least what's the name of the action so that i can assign a custom keyboard shortcut in the rubymine key map preferences? couldn't find anything [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/general-techniques-of-using-diagrams.html#select)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well duh.. it's `command + f`.. can't believe i didn't look there first